# Как получить средствами js внешний IP пользователя?

Tags: javascript, ip

Можно ли получить средствами js внешний ip пользователя? Нужны ли для этого доп библиотеки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. 
Можно получить внешний ip путем отправки запроса на сервер, например используя сторонний api:

```
fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
```